# POWERSHELL - Call Operator - What does this structure mean?

Tags: powershell, directoryservices, directorysearcher

this code runs well. It was copied from Microsoft.

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" 

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry 

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter 

$colProplist ="Name"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)} 

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll() 

foreach ($objResult in $colResults) 
   {$objItem = $objResult.Properties; $objItem.name }
```

However, I did not understand why the teacher have used

```
 $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
```

because all information I have got from web were this symbol & is for execute a code, once its meaning is "Call Operator".

I think that, in this case, it has an other meaning.

Comment: In this case the & sign has nothing to do with Powershell : the ADSearcher has a filter property that takes a string as value. Because the content is enclosed in double quotes the & sign is seen as a string (and not parsed by powershell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compound search/filter expression

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

is equivalent to the following conditional in programming language context:

```
objectCategory == person && objectClass == user
```

---

It is documented on [MSDN page for `DirectorySearcher.Filter Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Compound expressions are formed with the prefix operators `&` and `|`.
>   An example is "`(&(objectClass=user)(lastName= Davis))`". Another
>   example is "`(&(objectClass=printer)(|(building=42)(building=43)))`".

So, the filter is applied as:

```
objectClass=user && lastName= Davis
```

and

```
objectClass=printer && ( building=42 || building=43)
```

respectively, in the snippet provided.

Answer (score 1):

We talking about LDAP filter, take a look to [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475.aspx) for further information.  Your example is also discussed there.

Or take this way to get help inside Powershell:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-Help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter
```

... or online [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527.aspx)